# How to test if honeypot is working on a form?

Tags: 7, forms, testing, advertising

I have applied the [Honeypot](http://drupal.org/project/honeypot) module to my site and set it to protect all forms on the site.

The problem is I am unsure of how to test it to know that it is working as expected.

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open up firefox or chrome, and inspect the form (using firebug or any equivalent). If you see any element with the class 'honeypot-*' and a label 'Leave this field blank'. Then its a honeypot field and its enabled.

[image]

To check if it works. Make the element visible by changing `display: none` to `display: block`, enter a value into the input box and hit submit. The validation should fail.

Comment: Also, try enabling logging in Honeypot's settings, then check your Recent Log Entries page (in the Reports section of your site) after a day or two. I bet you'll find a few blocked spam attempts (or hundreds!).

Comment: Something that tripped me up for a few minutes: If you are logged in as "Admin", honeypot will not add the fields. Log out and check it again.

Comment: Mark's comment should be in the documentation of that module.... I was struggling about this "issue" for 1 hour...thanks @Mark!